# How to compress or minimize a video which is downloaded in chunks - JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am working on an application, where I am downloading multiple videos at the same time. Each video is downloaded in chunks and pushed to the array, which means for each downloaded video I have an array that I can convert into a blob and blob URI and can play them in the browser right after downloading. After that, create an array of objects and each object has few things properties like `video_name`, `size`, and `chunks` the structure looks like below:

```js
[
  {
    'video_name': 'video.mp4',
    'size': '23 mb',
    'chunks': []//Large array
  },
  .
  .
  .
]
```

At the end I download the array of objects as a json file, which I create like below:

```js
const download = (content, fileName, contentType) => {
  var a = document.createElement("a");
  var file = new Blob([content], {
    type: contentType
  });
  a.href = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  a.download = fileName;
  a.click();
};



//Contents are
download(
  JSON.stringify(data),
  "data.json",
  "text/json"
);

//NOTE: data is an object looks like data = { videos: [{}, {}, {} ...] }
```

Sometimes I have 30+ videos to download and the chunks make the object too large and the `JSON.strinify()` can't handle it and throw an error that says `object is too large` and exceeds the limit. Is there any way, I can compress or encode or minimize the big array of chunks and download the file, but the compression/encoding/minimization shouldn't be oneway, I should be able to uncompress it as well.

**Downloader**

```js
class Downloader {

  initializeDownload() {
    this._addDownloadState();
    this.videos.map(async video => {
      let name = video.split("/");
      const id =
        name[name.length - 2].split(".")[0] +
        "/" +
        name[name.length - 3] +
        "/" +
        name[name.length - 1];
      name.pop();
      const url = name.join("/");
      let response = await fetch(url, { method: "GET" });
      const reader = response.body.getReader();
      const contentLength = +response.headers.get("Content-Length");
      let receivedLength = 0;
      
      //Chunks for each video
      let chunks = [];

      while (true) {
        const { done, value } = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
          const event = new CustomEvent("onDownload", {
            detail: {
              id,
              chunks,
            },
          });
          window.dispatchEvent(event);
          break;
        }
        chunks.push(value);
        receivedLength += value.length;
        const event = new CustomEvent("onValueChanged", {
          detail: {
            progress: ((receivedLength / contentLength) * 100).toFixed(2),
            id,
          },
        });
        window.dispatchEvent(event);
      }
    });
  }

}
```

Comment: WTH would you convert blobs to JSON?

Comment: @Bergi I don't want to download the video itself but save it as a blob, and it's not actually converting blob to JSON but saving the file.

Comment: I mean converting the arrays of chunks (which are binary data) to JSON text. Don't do that. You write "*I have an array that I can convert into a blob*" - download that, not `JSON.stringify(data)`!

Comment: `I don't want to download the video itself but save it as a blob` means downloading the video. There is nothing to "save" unless its downloaded.

Comment: @Bergi the output I download without stringifying it is [object object]

Comment: @NadeemAhmad When I wrote "download", I didn't mean to literally pass `data` to your `download()` function. But really, what is your goal here? What does the user want to achieve, what are they going to do later with the file they're saving to disk?

Comment: @Bergi The videos are actually played through a URL, but when they are downloaded and the chunks are saved as objects, I want to save that whole big single object without downloading too. many videos. The purpose is that the user can play the videos on the app in offline mode as well.

Comment: Also, I will manage to read back the JSON file in offline mode.

Comment: Ah, *that* is what you want to do. A) there are (much) better solutions for offline storage than having the user save and restore files to/from disk B) Don't use JSON. If you want to put multiple videos in a single file, use a zip or tar archive or something similar. Do not store binary data as JSON.

Comment: Why did you delete your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68342442/how-to-implement-i18n-internationalization-in-single-spa-application?noredirect=1#comment120784320_68342442

Comment: It was marked -ve by someone that's why @Enigmativity

Comment: @NadeemAhmad - Negatives are fine. Just improve the question and move on. It's how we learn to ask good questions.